# Contract deployment & transactions inconsistently fail on Rinkeby test network?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether, remix

I'm using Infura & MetaMask and deploying to the Rinkeby test network. The contract compiles & runs without error in Remix. After compiling the contract in console, it deploys inconsistently. When it fails, I receive the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined
>   within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send.
>   Be aware that it might still be mined!

I also receive this error when performing transactions after successful deployment.

What is causing this error? Is this related to network congestion/traffic? I can post the contract, compile, and deploy code if it helps.

Comment: The error is sometimes misleading. See https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1102. It can also be due to blockchain congestion and/or low gas prices.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I believe this question is general enough if you'd like to use your comment as an answer.

Comment: Moved comment to answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is sometimes misleading. See http://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1102. It can also be due to blockchain congestion and/or low gas prices.